# Frozen poses after rendering animation

Tags: animation, pose-mode

I have rigged character and I want to make an animation. I set few kayframes with different poses. It shows up correctly on the timeline. And when I move the timeline character moves the way I desired. And here is the problem. When I render the animation [button render animation], all I get is frozen (almost) character without any movement. Almost, because bones with wiggle bone addon move on their own, the same with particle hair. **To summarize, after rendering is done I have frozen character with jiggling body and dynamic hair - the movement of the bones I set on the timeline is non-existant.**

I use blender 2.83 and eevee. The problem appears both when I use png format as well as any movie format. To answer questions, I don't think it's the problem with output directory, because blender renders animation - even with frozen bone movement. Also, I set start and end frame correctly - be it 10, 15, 20 frames. Kayframes are visible on the timeline - made with both auto keying and insert kayframe: LocRot. Rigged characters move when I move the timeline, it's only problem when I try to render it as animation. When I render it's as animation all I get is bunch of frames with characters frozen in one pose, but when I render random frame as image - I get correct pose that matches with the timeline.

**Could it be possible that I have bugged pose mode?** I made a test - I added sphere to the scene and in object mode I set movement of it (up and down). And it rendered it as animation correctly. Sphere moved up and down. **It seems that animation works with everything (moving objects, simulating dynamic hair) - except the bones.**

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found the reason of my problem. It was wiggle bone addon. It seems that you have to bake animation of wiggle bones and then turn it off, otherwise you will get frozen animation of any other bones.